# How to get changes from another branch

Tags: git

I am currently working on `featurex` branch. Our master branch is named `our-team`. Since I started working on `featurex`, more changes have been made to branch `our-team`.

I have done this locally to get all the latest changes from `our-team`:

```
git checkout our-team
git pull
```

Before I push `featurex` for merging, I would locally like to get all changes from `our-team` branch into `featurex` so that I can ensure everything works as expected.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can use [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), for instance, `git rebase our-team` when you are on your branch `featurex`.

It will move the start point of the branch at the end of your `our-team` branch, merging all changes in your `featurex` branch.

Comment: I will use this in the future, however, this time around I just did the following..does it have same affect? `git checkout our-team git pull git checkout featurex git merge our-team`

Comment: I'd like to stress:  if you do this and you *don't* have the changes from `our-team` locally you would need to run `git fetch && git rebase origin/our-team` instead.  Your commands assume that the repository has been updated prior.

Comment: DO NOT use rebase on public branches. This is the worst advice ever.

Comment: @OndrejSotolar Why?

Answer (score 257):

Before following these instructions keep in mind that `featurex` is the branch where changes are being merged and pushed

1. go to your branch `featurex`

   ```
   git checkout featurex
   ```
2. merge the changes of `our-team` branch into `featurex` branch

   ```
   git merge our-team
   ```

   or

   ```
   git cherry-pick {commit-hash}
   ```

   if you want to merge specific commits.

Note: probably you will have to fix conflicts after merging `our-team` branch into `featurex` branch before pushing.

Comment: I am relatively new to Git and had the problem that `git merge our-team` did not include the latest changes from the remote `our-team`, even after running `git fetch`. I had to first checkout `our-team`, do a `git pull`, then checkout `featurex` before merging. Git has a different way of thinking than me.

Comment: Based on the OP's description of what they want, `rebase` is what they need.

Answer (score 68):

```
git fetch origin our-team
```

or

```
git pull origin our-team
```

But first you should make sure that you are already on the branch you want to update (featurex).

Answer (score 41):

There are 2 options, either **merging** or **rebasing** your branch. Both work differently, but have similar outcomes.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37709368/12584714) is a **[rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)**. This will take all the commits done to `our-team` **and then** apply the commits done to `featurex`, prompting you to merge them as needed.

One bit caveat of rebasing is that you lose/rewrite your branch history, essentially telling git that your branch did not begin at commit 123abc but at commit 456cde. This *will* cause problems for other people working on the branch, and some remote tools will complain about it. If you are sure about what you are doing though, that's what the `--force` flag is for.

What [other posters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42503177/12584714) are suggesting is a **[merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)**. This will take the `featurex` branch, with whatever state it has and try to merge it with the current state of `our-team`, prompting you to do one, big, merge commit and fix all the merge errors before pushing to `our-team`. The difference is that you are applying your `featurex` commits **before** the `our-team` new commits and then fixing the differences. You also do not rewrite history, instead adding one commit to it instead of rewriting those that came before.

Both options are valid and can work in tandem. What is usually (by that I mean, if you are using widespread tools and methodology such as [git-flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)) done for a feature branch is to merge it into the main branch, often going through a merge-request, and solve all the conflicts that arise into one (or multiple) merge commits.

Rebasing is an interesting option, that may help you fix your branch before eventually going through a merge, and ease the pain of having to do one big merge commit.

Comment: Thanks for this. What I really dislike about git is that there always seem to be several answers to a question, on which even the experts disagree, and I, as a noob user who is forced to use it, must somehow pick the right one. And if I pick the wrong one then git will punish me, because there is no simple undo option. Well, there are probably many undo options, but then we start all over again :-(

Comment: One thing that you can do to alleviate this is by making "backup branches". Before undertaking a big change you can always a do a `git checkout -b my-backup` this is not a complete/proper backup, but it'll save you some headaches if the merge/rebase goes sideways.
So long as you do not push it and clean it up afterward, there's no real drawbacks to doing that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining difference between the two.

Answer (score 20):

You are almost there :)

All that is left is to

```
git checkout featurex
git merge our-team
```

This will merge our-team into featurex.

The above assumes you have already committed/stashed your changes in featurex, if that is not the case you will need to do this first.

Answer (score -4):

incase someone stumbles upon this asking themselves how to pull in changes without using git pull - git pull will first run git fetch then git merge as it makes up the combination of two sequences i.e. fetch + merge. For those that need to just pull changes from another branch without doing so:

```
git checkout <branch with changes wanted> 
git checkout -b <new branch>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).