# How to compare a forked branch with its original one?

Tags: git

Yet I've seen similar questions, git is still not easy to grasp, so here goes my version of main current problem.

I have the `dev` branch. Then I create my own dev branch with `git checkout -b my_dev`.

I work in this branch, while other developers are working on their own forked dev branches. Eventually the main `dev` branch is updated and I want to keep `my_dev` branch in sync with `dev`.

What is the best approach for that? Consider two scenários: with and without conflict.

It's important that I can see what's being changed upstream in `dev` when compared with mine. My first idea was to use `git diff dev my_dev`(and vice-versa) but, surprisingly, it only shows the **files I've changed**. It didn't showed nothing from upstream `dev`.

I did `git fetch --all` for sure too.

So far, the best I could get was using github and doing a **pull request** which nicely shows all the diffs and files that are in `dev` and not in `my_dev`. But I should be able to use only `git cli`, right?

Comment: Are you dealing with one upstream (GitHub?) repository, or *two* upstream repositories, in addition to your own local repository?

Comment: If you compare with `origin/dev` instead of `dev`, do you see the changes you expect ?

Comment: @torek: yes, just one upstream repository so far

Comment: @LeGEC: after `git fetch --all` this does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with ... (3 dots):

```
git diff origin/dev...my_dev # the stuff I have done
git diff my_dev...origin/dev # the stuff they have done
```

Comment: I've seen thing like these `...` and I thought it was just snips. Yet, no matter the order I use it, I still see the changes on my side. Git is definitely not intuitive, why these `...`?

Comment: If you want to see changes on their side it's `your-branch...base-branch`. Three dots asks git to find the last common ancestor and diff from there instead of the first argument.

Comment: Now my colleague has committed something ahead in `dev`, I can test your suggestion. Indeed it works. But now, for a complete answer, how do get his changes?
And what if there's conflict?

Comment: I've tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/42503177/2534342, but `git diff origin/dev...my_dev` still shows the differences!