# How to copy changes from one feature branch to another feature branch derived from same parent branch

Tags: git

How I can get the latest changes from the release branch into my branch without losing my changes?

```
develop---- A ----------------------------------
       |    |
       |    my branch----commit A
       |
       release branch ----- commit A ------ commit B ------
```

I will be raising a pull request to the release branch, hence I want to get the latest code from the release branch to mine, to minimize the differences.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [How to get changes from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709298/how-to-get-changes-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I need to copy a file or some changes inside a directory from a branch to current branch and I simply run this command.

```
git checkout SOURCE_BRANCH path/to/dir/or/file.ext
```

All difference are staged and then you can commit all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to merge the release branch to your branch and then resolve the conflicts.

```
git checkout release_branch
git pull
git checkout my_branch
git merge --squash release_branch
```

Then if there are merge conflicts, resolve them, and commit.

Since you will be raising a pull request, you will have to resolve merge conflicts sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout release_branch
git pull
git checkout mybranch
git merge --squash release_branch
git push origin release_branch
```

This is all if you intend to not merge your changes back to `master`. Generally it is a good practice to merge all your changes back to `master`, and create new branches off of that.

Also, after the merge command, you will have some conflicts, which you will have to edit manually and fix.