# Take changes from one feature branch to another feature branch

Tags: git

I have a `feature-a` and `feature-b` both branched from `master` something like this:

```
         E --- F --- G feature-a
        /
---A---B---.... master
    \
     H --- I --- J feature-b
```

Our usual workflow is we create a pull request per feature and once the feature is done it is squashed and merged into master.

`feature-a` has some files that are dependent on changes made in `feature-b`.

Usually, I'd wait for `feature-a` to be done and squash-merged into master, then rebase `feature-b` onto the head of `master` and make necessary changes on `feature-b`, but is there another, cleaner way to do this without having to wait for `feature-a` to be finished that would keep committing history clean?

Comment: If you're using squash merges, that's going to limit your options a lot, because it means the history of feature branches is regularly thrown away, defeating a lot of the functionality that git has for tracking the relationships between them.

Comment: Why not merge `feature-b` into `feature-a` or rebase `feature-a` onto `feature-b` or cherry-pick the relevant changes from `feature-b` into `feature-a`?

Comment: I already had the PR's for both a and b set to merge into `master` on github. I've decided go with what you said and rebase `feature-a` onto `feature-b` and have the PR for `feature-b` set to squash-merge into `feature-a` on github. `feature-a` would then merge into `master`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 : could you copy your comment as an answer ? the OP seems satisfied with it.

Comment: I'd rather vote to close this as duplicate of [How to get changes from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709298/how-to-get-changes-from-another-branch)